# Not able to do this.Context.Users.Load()

Tags: entity-framework

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896376.aspx here it says about a  load method

```
this.context = new MyEntities();
this.Context.Users.
```

but i am not able to do   this.Context.Users.Load()

i am not able to find the method load
what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't offer you `Load` method it means that `Users` **is not** `EntityCollection<User>`. It is either `ObjectQuery<User>`, `ObjectSet<User>` or `DbSet<User>`. Instead of `Load` use:

```
var data = this.context.Users.ToList();
```

It also answers question what should you do? You should learn to use your IDE to identify correct type before you start searching in documentation.